# How do I ensure all values show up in field concatenated from multiple rows?

Tags: crystal-reports, concatenation

I have report where each sales code is listed individually.

So the tables output this

| Client | Date | Sales Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/17/22 | X23 |
| 2 | 9/18/22 | A24 |
| 2 | 9/18/22 | B12 |

But I'm needing to see

| Client | Date | Sales Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/17/22 | X23 |
| 2 | 9/18/22 | A24 B12 |

I found a formula online and it mostly works

> Formula 1: this formula concatenates each value into one string. Place in Details section and suppress the field.
>
> WhilePrintingRecords;
> Shared StringVar ConCat;
> If ConCat = "" then ConCat := {Field_Name} else if not({Field_Name} in ConCat) then ConCat := ConCat + " " + {Field_Name}
>
> Formula 2: this formula will display the final value. Place in Group Footer section.
>
> WhilePrintingRecords;
> Shared StringVar ConCat;
>
> Formula 3: this formula will reset the variable for the next record. Place in Group Header to remove previous record's value.
>
> WhilePrintingRecords;
> Shared StringVar ConCat := ""

The problem I'm having is that if two consecutive dates have the same sales code they get merged. Group A is the client id and Group B is the date. These formulas are put in the Group B footer and header. And this is set up for two fields (which can sometimes have blanks)

So if normally have this

| Client | Date | Sales Code | Transaction Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/17/22 | X23 |  |
| 2 | 9/18/22 | A24 | 125 |
| 2 | 9/20/22 | A24 | 333 |
| 2 | 9/24/22 | B13 | 908 |
| 2 | 9/24/22 | K17 | 227 |

I'm getting this

| Client | Date | Sales Code | Transaction Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/17/22 | X23 |  |
| 2 | 9/18/22 | A24 | 125 333 |
| 2 | 9/24/22 | B13 K17 | 908 227 |

Instead of

| Client | Date | Sales Code | Transaction Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/17/22 | X23 |  |
| 2 | 9/18/22 | A24 | 125 |
| 2 | 9/20/22 | A24 | 333 |
| 2 | 9/24/22 | B13 K17 | 908 227 |

Since there are two groups I tried messing around the placement within the groups but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new formula and combine these 3 "key" fields and then replace your group with this formula instead. That should keep everything separated nicely:

Update formula if Client is a number or a string..

```
// My grouping formula
ToText({My_Table.Client},0,'') & '-' & 
ToText({My_Table.Date},'yyyy-MM-dd') & '-' & 
{My_Table.Sales_Code}
```

**-- UPDATE 1**

If the client field is a string do this:

```
// My grouping formula
{My_Table.Client} & '-' & 
ToText({My_Table.Date},'yyyy-MM-dd') & '-' & 
{My_Table.Sales_Code}
```

Adam (APB Reports)

Comment: The part **0,''** is tell me Too many arguments have been given to this function

Comment: It’s a string then. Make it like SALES_Code.

Comment: How do I do that?